# Why do most (or at least just my :P) motherboard default CSM on?

Tags: motherboard, bios, uefi

I'm just a bit confused as to why the would do this since UEFI is supposed to be the successor to BIOS. It just seems ridiculous that if the motherboard uses UEFI instead of a BIOS, it would default to emulating a BIOS system.

Comment: If you ever try to install a new OS into a secure-boot-UEFI-only PC, then you might reconsider. I had this issue many times with laptops locked down so hard - it is very difficult to re-install the OS (even when we try to re-install Windows 10 on it that supports UEFI and secure boot).

Comment: Computers that ship with Windows 8 and later would normally ship with the CSM disabled. This is because Microsoft requires that Secure Boot be enabled, and with many UEFIs, the CSM and Secure Boot are mutually exclusive. For a bare motherboard (or a computer that does *not* ship with Windows), Microsoft's requirements don't come into play. I have several such computers, but I don't recall what their default settings were. If a board ships with the CSM enabled, I can only speculate that it's to improve compatibility with older OSes.

Answer (score 1):

Better compatibility if you're installing an arbitrary OS I suppose.

*Anything* will work with CSM. I guess they're making the assumption (correct or otherwise) that whoever's setting up the system may not choose to install the handful of OSes that support secure boot.

If you do need it switched on, its trivial, and it saves them support calls from people trying to install say, windows 7 and not having it boot.

Comment: Secure Boot is not synonymous with EFI/UEFI. Lots of older EFI implementations don't even support Secure Boot, and most newer ones support disabling Secure Boot while still booting in EFI mode, without enabling the CSM. (I've heard of some implementations that link the CSM and Secure Boot, so that enabling one necessitates disables the other; but I have yet to encounter that myself.) In most cases, enabling the CSM complicates the boot path, which can lead to confusing problems. See [my Web page on the subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for details.